# Probability that user will uninstall the app under N days

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let's assume that we have data about user activity in the app and we want to calculate the probability that the user will uninstall the app under N days. In the data, we have different time ranges for user activity, some of the users are active since we started to log the data and some just recently started to use our app.

From my perspective, the most intuitive way to calculate the probability is using the formula:

$P(uninstall<N\:days) = \frac{number\:of\:users\:who\:uninstalled\:under\:N\:days}{number\:of\:users\:who\:uninstalled\:under\:N\:days\:OR\:didn't\:uninstalled\:\ge\:N\:days}$

This is because, from all users, I want to exclude users who are still active but they installed the app earlier than N days. For example, if we want to calculate the probability for 10 days, it doesn't make sense to include in the formula users who installed the app before 5 days and still using it. Because we don't know whether that specific user will uninstall the app after 8 or 80 days of using.

Questions:

1. Does this formula make sense to you? If not, how to calculate the probability that the user will uninstall the app under N days?
2. I have in mind two more formulas but I'm not sure how to interpret them:

$P(X) = \frac{number\:of\:users\:who\:uninstalled\:under\:N\:days}{number\:of\:all\ users}$

$P(Y) = \frac{number\:of\:users\:who\:uninstalled\:under\:N\:days}{number\:of\:all\ users\:who\:uninstall\:the\:app}$

3. I want to plot days (x-axis) over probability (y-axis) and get something like CDF. Using the first formula that I've mentioned, I have something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FJqc.jpg. The problem is that if we want to interpret the plot for some high numbers, it'll mean that the probability that the user will uninstall the app is 100% or very close. Am I wrong somewhere and is there a way to add something like confidence interval into this interpretation?

Comment: [tag:survival-analysis]?

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I've heard about the "survival analysis" term. I'll check that.